# How to store li with text and images in localstorage with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, local-storage

I have created a shopping list program in html and javascript.I am a beginner and doesn't know how to implement localstorage to store the list items. I am inserting the complete code for the program to better explain what actually I want to store in local storage. It consists of an input field for entering item names and a button which on click sets the entered text as a list item. List item then have two images, one for marking it done and other for removing the item from the list. So every list item in the shopping list contains two child nodes of images. Don't know how to do this for localstorage. Any help please

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var add = document.getElementById('add');
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var bottom = document.getElementById('bottom');

add.onclick = ShoppingList;

function ShoppingList(){
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var imageDone = document.createElement('img');
  var imageRemove = document.createElement('img');
  
  imageDone.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-ui-icons/512/tick_green.png');
  
  imageRemove.setAttribute('src', 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/trash_recyclebin_empty_closed.png');
  
  li.textContent = input.value;
  li.appendChild(imageRemove);
  li.appendChild(imageDone);
  bottom.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
  input.focus();
  imageDone.onclick = function(){
    li.removeChild(imageRemove);
  };
  imageRemove.onclick = function(){
    bottom.removeChild(li);
  };
  
  li.ondblclick = function(){
    bottom.removeChild(li);
  };
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto; 
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
}

#top, #bottom {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
 
}

#input {
  width: 220px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #84ac47;

}

#add {
  width: 73px;
  padding: 9px;
  margin:0
  outline: none;
  background: #67c100;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  line-height:36px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left:0;
  padding-left:0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  color: #67c100;
 
  
}

img {
  float: right;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="shoppinglist.css">
  <title>Shopping List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Shopping List</h2>
  <div id='top'><!--
  --><input type="text" id="input"><!--
  --><button id="add">ADD</button>
  </div>
  
  <div id='bottom'>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="shoppinglist.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var items = [];
var index = 0;

function createListItem(text, done, dontStore) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var imageRemove = document.createElement('img');

  imageRemove.setAttribute('src', 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/trash_recyclebin_empty_closed.png');

  li.textContent = text;
  var i = index;
  if (!dontStore) {
    items[index++] = {text: text, done: false};
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
  }
  li.appendChild(imageRemove);
  if (!done) {
    var imageDone = document.createElement('img');
    imageDone.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-ui-icons/512/tick_green.png');
    li.appendChild(imageDone);
    imageDone.onclick = function(){
      li.removeChild(imageRemove);
      items[i].done = true;
      localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    };
  }
  bottom.appendChild(li);

  function remove() {
    bottom.removeChild(li);
    delete items[i];
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
  }
  imageRemove.onclick = remove;

  li.ondblclick = remove;
}

function ShoppingList() {
  createListItem(input.value);
  input.value = "";
  input.focus();
}


items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items') || '[]');
items.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item) {
    createListItem(item.text, item.done, true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain whats going on with code above please.

Comment: @knight The code save shopping list in a `items` array and save that array in localStorage, the array need to be first stringified and on load it load the array from localStorage and parse the string, then it iterate over the array and recreate the shopping list.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't see any add button click event. Can you please share working jsfiddle so I can have better understanding of what really making things happen. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @knight the rest of the code is the same, here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tz999Leq/

Comment: Thanks jc ubic it really helped and I appreciated your efforts. Thanks again

Comment: it only stores 3 items and the rest of them vanish after browsers refresh. Any clue?

Comment: Thank you. And now I found another problem, the items are not removing from localstorage permanently. They only disappear from viewport and when I refresh the browser they are still there.

Comment: It still has problems. Try adding more than five items and then try to delete items by double click and click on bin icon. Some items still there. Don't know whats happening.

Comment: Great, it worked as I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help.